# Combining two columns from two data frames in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark

Consider we have two dataframes

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(a=107831, f="test1"),
    Row(a=125231, f=None),
])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(a=107831, f=None),
    Row(a=125231, f="test2"),
])
```

How to kind of combine the two dataframes and get one with the following df?

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(a=107831, f="test1"),
    Row(a=125231, f="test2"),
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Join both data frames on `a` column then use **`coalsce`** function.

```
df1.alias("t1").join(df2.alias("t2"),["a"],'inner').\
select("t1.a",coalesce("t1.f","t2.f").alias("f")).\
show()
#+------+-----+
#|     a|    f|
#+------+-----+
#|107831|test1|
#|125231|test2|
#+------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I did pyspark, buy you can get what you want by doing something like this.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when

df3 = df1.join(df2, df1.a == df2.a).select(df1.a, df1.f.alias('d1f'), df2.f.alias('d2f'))

# build a new column conditionally select either df1.f or df2.f
df4 = df3.withColumn('f', when(col('d1f').isNull(), df3.d2f).otherwise(df3.d1f))

df4.show()
+------+-----+-----+-----+
|     a|  d1f|  d2f|    f|
+------+-----+-----+-----+
|107831|test1| null|test1|
|125231| null|test2|test2|
+------+-----+-----+-----+

# drop off the 2 temporary columns
df4 = df4.drop('d1f','d2f')

df4.show()
+------+-----+
|     a|    f|
+------+-----+
|107831|test1|
|125231|test2|
+------+-----+
```